# Single on event for multiple transitions

Tags: d3.js

I'm modifying [this example](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) to have multiple lines and updating it to use v4. [The code I wrote](https://jsfiddle.net/AltayH/umoqrhgj/6/) works, but the way my update function recurses is particularly inelegant:

```
function repeat() {
  paths.each(d => d.push(random()));
  paths.attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear);
  paths.each(d => d.shift());
  d3.select({}).transition().duration(750).on('end', repeat);
}
```

Note the transition on an empty selection just to create a 750 ms timeout between calls. I wanted to do this instead:

```
function repeat() {
  paths.each(d => d.push(random()));
  paths.attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .on('end', repeat);
  paths.each(d => d.shift());
}
```

However, this results in multiple concurrent calls to `repeat`, one for each element in the selection.

Is there a way I can simplify my code to get rid of the extra transition? It seems like there must be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3-transitions can be a bit tricky because the end event triggers at the end of each element's transition. There is no `transition.on("endAll", ...`, so since you don't want to trigger the repeat function twice at the end of the transition you are using an empty transition to delay calling repeat.

You could use a counter to see when the last transition is done, but this too is less clean. Ultimately, you will get less elegant code when managing multiple events with transitions that act on elements individually.

Instead, since each element's timer and transition events for a d3-transition are specific to that element (even if you set them as a group, each element has it's own timer and events), create a repeat function that is specific to each element:

```
function scroll(d) {
   d.push(Math.random());

   // Transition
   d3.select(this).attr("transform",null)
     .attr("d",line)
     .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750) 
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)  
      .on("end",scroll);  // repeat

   d.shift();
}
```

And call with `selection.each(scroll);` Now we are managing each transition (which handles each item in a selection separately) with a function that handles one item in the selection at a time.

This allows you to:

- drop the empty transition,
- access `d` directly if you call this function with `.each()` (instead of using `paths.each(...` twice in the function),

Other considerations:

- you can apply this function to any group of paths you have a selection for without modifying the function itself.
- the element being transitioned is `this`

Here it is at work:

```js
let n = 40;
let random = d3.randomUniform(-1, 1);

let data = [d3.range(n).map(random), d3.range(n).map(random)];

let margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 6, left: 40};
let width = 960 - margin.right;
let height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, n - 2])
    .range([0, width]);

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

let line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

let svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

let paths = svg.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'lines')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .selectAll('path').data(data).enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('stroke', (d, i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i])
    .attr('d', line)
 .each(scroll);
 
 
function scroll(d) {
   d.push(random());
          
   d3.select(this).attr("transform",null)
     .attr("d",line)
     .transition()
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
       .duration(750)
       .ease(d3.easeLinear)  
       .on("end",scroll);

  d.shift();
}
```

```css
#lines {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.y.axis path {
    stroke: black;
}
p {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks much cleaner. Is there any particular reason you added the conditional to `d.shift()` and moved it before the transition? Is it good practice to separate the data management from the transition creation?

Comment: @Altay_H, You could keep it below - I moved it up just to keep the data manipulation together - not sure why I had the conditional now that I look at it, I've removed it (It must have been too early to think straight, thanks for catching it).

Comment: You need the conditional if you move it before the creation of the transition otherwise there isn't sufficient data and the right edge of the graph goes wonky. Basically you need to have n + 1 elements at all times.

Comment: @Altay_H, yeah I just realized that - I've moved the shift() below the transition as it was in your original. Guess I was paying attention when I moved the push() and shift() together.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/d3-js/WC_7Xi6VV50/j1HK0vIWI-EJ

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, hadn't seen it (or that implementation) it is an interesting approach - I've previously recommended a less sophisticated end all method (incrementing on end event, triggering if increment indicates all transitions are done), will remember this.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: This is a D3 **v5** answer! Although the question uses v4 this might prove helpful for future reference.

---

As of [v1.2.0](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/releases/tag/v1.2.0) of the [d3-transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) module there is [`transition.end()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_end) which

> Returns a promise that resolves when every selected element finishes transitioning.

Starting with D3 [v5.8.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v5.8.0) this was introduced into the main bundle. This is the modern implementation of what Andrew Reid described in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088258/4235784) as the `endAll` event, i.e. an event that is fired once all transitions of the selection have come to an end.

Your `repeat()` function can easily be rewritten as:

```
function repeat() {
  paths.each(d => d.push(random()));
  paths.attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .end()                           // Get the promise.
      .then(() => {                  // Once resolved when all transitions have ended...
        paths.each(d => d.shift());  // ...shift the data array...
        repeat();                    // ...and start a new iteration.
      });
}
```

Have a look at the following demo to see it in action:

```js
let n = 40;
let random = d3.randomUniform(-1, 1);

let data = [d3.range(n).map(random), d3.range(n).map(random)];

let margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 6, left: 40};
let width = 960 - margin.right;
let height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, n - 2])
    .range([0, width]);

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

let line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

let svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

let paths = svg.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'lines')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .selectAll('path').data(data).enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('stroke', (d, i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i]);

repeat();

function repeat() {
  paths.each(d => d.push(random()));
  
  paths.attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .end()
        .then(() => {
          paths.each(d => d.shift());
          repeat();
        })
}
```

```css
#lines {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.y.axis path {
    stroke: black;
}
p {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, rewritten using ES8 [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax:

```js
let n = 40;
let random = d3.randomUniform(-1, 1);

let data = [d3.range(n).map(random), d3.range(n).map(random)];

let margin = {top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 6, left: 40};
let width = 960 - margin.right;
let height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, n - 2])
    .range([0, width]);

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

let line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

let svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

let paths = svg.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'lines')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .selectAll('path').data(data).enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('stroke', (d, i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i]);

(async function repeat() {
  paths.each(d => d.push(random()));
  
  await paths.attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ")")
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .end();
  
  paths.each(d => d.shift());
  repeat();
})()
```

```css
#lines {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.y.axis path {
    stroke: black;
}
p {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script>
```